# KILL process with input as process name and time

Tags: kill

I am trying to write a shell script to kill a specified process if it runs more than specified time and get process information before killing.

Note: Script should take process name and time as input. What I have tried so far is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -eaf |
awk '{print $7, $8}' |
sort -n |
grep -v TIME |
grep -v 00:00:00 |
awk -F ":" '{if ( $2 >= 01 ) print}'
```

the o/p prints as follows:

```
00:08:15 /usr/bin/dockerd
00:17:41 /usr/bin/kubelet
```

this is where I stuck ... I need to kill which are more than 01 min so the above process needs to be killed using a script input as process name and time.

Comment: Why don't you just run the process with `timeout` (from GNU coreutils)?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you are in a cul-de-sac and there is no way to do what do you want that way.

The problem is that your `TIME` information is stale because, probably, the `TIME` property of that processes changed while the script is running. The couple `TIME`, `CMD` cannot identify a process.

Why do you do `awk '{print $7, $8}'`? At that point you do not need the `CMD`, you need only the `PID` to identify the process, so simply change it to `awk '{print $7, $2}'`.

You could change your code as follows to print the `PID`s of the processes you are searching for:

```
ps -eaf \
| awk '{print $7, $2}' \
| sort -n \
| grep -v TIME \
| grep -v 00:00:00 \
| awk -F ":" '{if ( $2 >= 01 ) print}' \
| awk '{print $2}'
```

In addition, your code has a subtle bug: what happens if a process has `04:00:23` as `TIME`? Your code will skip it because checks only *minutes* field in `TIME`. You can fix it this way:

```
ps -eaf \
| awk '{print $7, $2}' \
| sort -n \
| grep -v TIME \
| grep -v 00:00:00 \
| awk -F ":" '{if (( $1 >= 01 ) || ( $2 >= 01 )) print}' \
| awk '{print $2}'
```

Some suggestions to improve your skills:

- You should check the `-o` option of `ps` and the `-F` option of `awk` and, perhaps, the meaning of `TIME` column of `ps`.
- Try to understand how the following line works:

  ```
  ps -eo time,pid --no-headers | awk -F '[ :]*' '$1>0 || $2>0 {print $4}' | xargs kill
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CPU time in second along with pid and command with:

```
ps -Ao time= -o pid= -o comm= |
  perl -lpe 's/^(\d+-)?(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/(($1*24+$2)*60+$3)*60+$4/e'
```

You can do the killing with `perl` as well:

```
ps -Ao time= -o pid= -o comm= |
  perl -lne '
    if (/^(\d+-)?(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/) {
      $cputime = (($1*24+$2)*60+$3)*60+$4;
      $pid = $5;
      $comm = $6;
      if ($cputime > 60) {
        print "$pid ($comm) has used $cputime seconds of CPU, killing it";
        kill "TERM", $pid or warn "kill($pid): $!\n";
      }
    }'
```